# How to share base theme between light & dark theme Material 3 Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, material3

#### I want both light and dark theme to share a base because that's where I configure button shape, font size, etc.

###### However when I try to use `copyWith()` off off the base instance of `ThemeData`, my darkTheme copies the colors from lightTheme.

#### How can I fix this so that darkTheme & lightTheme respect Material3 values while sharing a common base?

```dart
final base = ThemeData(
  useMaterial3: true,
  colorSchemeSeed: const Color(0xFF2C6C2F),
  textTheme: const TextTheme(
    bodySmall: TextStyle(),
    bodyMedium: TextStyle(),
    bodyLarge: TextStyle(),
    titleSmall: TextStyle(),
    titleMedium: TextStyle(),
    titleLarge: TextStyle(
      fontSize: 20,
      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
    ),
  ).apply(),
  elevatedButtonTheme: ElevatedButtonThemeData(
    style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
      textStyle: const TextStyle(fontSize: 15),
      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
        vertical: 10,
        horizontal: 30,
      ),
      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
      ),
    ),
  ),
  textButtonTheme: TextButtonThemeData(
    style: TextButton.styleFrom(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
        vertical: 10,
        horizontal: 30,
      ),
    ),
  ),
  outlinedButtonTheme: OutlinedButtonThemeData(
    style: OutlinedButton.styleFrom(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
        vertical: 10,
        horizontal: 30,
      ),
      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
      ),
    ),
  ),
);

final darkTheme = customTheme(base, brightness: Brightness.dark);

final lightTheme = customTheme(base, brightness: Brightness.light);

ThemeData customTheme(ThemeData base, {required Brightness brightness}) {
  return base.copyWith(brightness: brightness);
}
```